# Null check operator used on a null value error in flutter Dashboard page

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this error when I am running the app. I could not figure out why this error occurred.
So I am switching a project to flutter null safety but i am getting Null check operator used on a null value error i tried looking into other similar issues tried but its not working for me the complete error is as following

Stack Trace

> The following _CastError was thrown building DashboardPage(dirty,
> dependencies: [_InheritedTheme,
> _InheritedProviderScope<DocumentSnapshot?>, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#556e8]], state:
> _DashboardPageState#0b8da): Null check operator used on a null value
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:   DashboardPage

My main.app

```
void main() => runApp(ElectricalIssueTrackerApp());

class ElectricalIssueTrackerApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const appName = 'Electrical Issue Tracker';
  static const appIcon = AssetImage('assets/icons/192.png');
  static const appLegalese = 'GNU General Public License v3.0';
  // Move to Misc
  static const appIssueTracker =
      '';
  // Move to Misc
  static const appIssueTrackerMailing = '';

  static const appRepository =
      '';

  const ElectricalIssueTrackerApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: appName,
      theme: _theme,
      home: FutureBuilder<FirebaseApp>(
        future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          // Loading screen, when initializing firebase app.
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Loading();
          }

          return Authenticated(
            child: Verified(
              child: DashboardPage(),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  static const _primary = Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 38, 70);
  static const _accent = Color.fromARGB(255, 245, 248, 253);
  static const _secondary = Color(0xFF924642);
  static const _vistaWhite = Color(0xFFFEF9F7);

  static const _fontFamily = 'Ubuntu';

  static get _theme {
    return ThemeData(
      visualDensity: VisualDensity.standard,
      fontFamily: _fontFamily,
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      primaryColor: _primary,
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
        primary: _primary,
        onPrimary: _accent,
        secondary: _secondary,
        onSecondary: _vistaWhite,
        surface: _accent,
        onSurface: _primary,
        background: _accent,
        onBackground: _primary,
      ),
      disabledColor: Color(0x99002646),
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: _accent,
      cardColor: Colors.white,
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        color: _accent,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: _primary,
        ),
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
          statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        ),
        elevation: 0,
        actionsIconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: _primary,
        ),
        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: _fontFamily,
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          letterSpacing: 0.5,
          color: _primary,
        ),
      ),
      bottomSheetTheme: BottomSheetThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
        elevation: 8,
      ),
      iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
        color: _primary,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
        backgroundColor: _primary,
        foregroundColor: _accent,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        ),
      ),
      outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
        style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: _primary,
          primary: _accent,
          onSurface: _accent,
        ),
      ),
      dialogTheme: DialogTheme(
        backgroundColor: _accent,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
        ),
      ),
      snackBarTheme: const SnackBarThemeData(
        backgroundColor: _primary,
        contentTextStyle: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: _fontFamily,
          color: _accent,
          letterSpacing: 0.5,
        ),
      ),
      inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
        filled: true,
        fillColor: _accent,
        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: _primary),
        ),
        errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
        ),
        focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
        ),
        labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: _primary, fontSize: 14),
        focusColor: _primary,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My Dashboard.app

```
class DashboardPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashboardPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DashboardPageState createState() => _DashboardPageState();

  static _DashboardPageState of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.findAncestorStateOfType<_DashboardPageState>()!;
}

class _DashboardPageState extends State<DashboardPage> {
  bool _raiseNewIssueFormIsShown = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);

    final misc = Provider.of<MiscSnapshot>(context).misc;

    final userSnapshot = Provider.of<UserSnapshot>(context);
    final user = userSnapshot.user;

    NetworkImage? userPhoto;

    final photoUrl = Provider.of<User>(context).photoURL;

    if (photoUrl != null) {
      userPhoto = NetworkImage(photoUrl);
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: FadeInLeft(
          preferences: const AnimationPreferences(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
          ),
          child: Text(
            _raiseNewIssueFormIsShown
                ? 'Raise an issue'
                : ElectricalIssueTrackerApp.appName,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
            onTap: () => showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (_) => MiscellaneousDialog(userSnapshot),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: PhysicalModel(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                elevation: 3,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: theme.primaryColor,
                  child: Text(
                    ('${user.name}${user.email}-'[0]).toUpperCase(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: theme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                    ),
                  ),
                  foregroundImage: userPhoto,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: CupertinoScrollbar(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Wrap(
            spacing: 10,
            runSpacing: 30,
            children: [
              // The analytics widget
              ActiveAndResolvedIssueCounters(misc: misc),

              // View all active issues if user has permission
              if (user.scope.canViewActiveIssues) ActiveIssuesSection(),

              if (user.scope.canViewResolvedIssues)
                buildResolvedIssuesButton(misc, userSnapshot),

              // Raise an issue section
              if (user.scope.canCreateIssue) RaiseAnIssueSection(),

              // All issues raised by the user.
              MyIssuesSection(),

              // Footer
              SizedBox(height: 30),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> showRaiseNewIssueForm(BuildContext context) async {
    setState(() => _raiseNewIssueFormIsShown = true);

    await Scaffold.of(context)
        .showBottomSheet((_) => RaiseNewIssueBottomSheet())
        .closed;

    setState(() => _raiseNewIssueFormIsShown = false);
  }

  Widget buildResolvedIssuesButton(Misc misc, UserSnapshot userSnapshot) {
    return Center(
      child: OutlinedButton(
        child: Text('View already resolved issues'),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) {
              return MultiProvider(
                providers: [
                  Provider.value(value: userSnapshot),
                  Provider.value(value: misc),
                ],
                child: ResolvedIssuesPage(),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

raise_issue_section.dart

```
class RaiseAnIssueSection extends StatelessWidget {
  const RaiseAnIssueSection({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);

    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: theme.cardColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
        // color: theme.colorScheme.surface,
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Having an electrical issue in campus?',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: theme.primaryColor,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 18),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              FloatingActionButton.extended(
                onPressed: () =>
                    DashboardPage.of(context).showRaiseNewIssueForm(context),
                label: Text('Raise new issue'),
                icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.feather),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

misc.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'misc.freezed.dart';

typedef MiscSnapshot = DocumentSnapshot<Misc>;

@freezed
class Misc with _$Misc {
  const Misc._();

  const factory Misc._create({
    required List<String> locationBlocks,
    required int activeIssuesCount,
    required int resolvedIssuesCount,
  }) = _Misc;

  static const _LocationBlocksKey = 'location-blocks';
  static const _ActiveIssuesCountKey = 'active-issues-count';
  static const _ResolvedIssuesCountKey = 'resolved-issues-count';

  static final _ref =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('misc').withConverter<Misc>(
    fromFirestore: (snapshot, options) {
      final data = snapshot.data()!;

      return Misc._create(
          locationBlocks: data[_LocationBlocksKey].cast<String>(),
          activeIssuesCount: data[_ActiveIssuesCountKey],
          resolvedIssuesCount: data[_ResolvedIssuesCountKey]);
    },
    toFirestore: (value, options) {
      return {
        _LocationBlocksKey: value.locationBlocks,
      };
    },
  ).doc('default');

  static get ref => _ref;

  static Stream<MiscSnapshot> get watch => _ref.snapshots();

  static Future<MiscSnapshot> get read => _ref.get();

  static Future<void> informIssueCreated() async {
    await _ref.update({
      _ActiveIssuesCountKey: FieldValue.increment(1),
    });
  }

  static Future<void> informIssueResolved() async {
    await _ref.update({
      _ActiveIssuesCountKey: FieldValue.increment(-1),
      _ResolvedIssuesCountKey: FieldValue.increment(1),
    });
  }

  static Future<void> informActiveIssuePurged() async {
    await _ref.update({
      _ActiveIssuesCountKey: FieldValue.increment(-1),
    });
  }

  static Future<void> updateActiveIssuesCount(int value) async {
    assert(value >= 0, 'bad argument: cannot write negative value');

    if (value < 0) {
      return;
    }

    await _ref.update({_ActiveIssuesCountKey: value});
  }
}

extension MiscSnapshotExtension on MiscSnapshot {
  Misc get misc => this.data()!;
}
```

Comment: can you please add the stack trace of the error ?

Comment: @MichaelSoliman stack trace added

Comment: Can you try with `Provider...(context,listen: false)`

Answer (score 0):

You'll mostly get the "Null check operator used on a null value"-error when ever you explicitly say something is not null using the bang operator `!` on something that actually is.

Looking at your code sample that could be in the following lines:

```
static _DashboardPageState of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.findAncestorStateOfType<_DashboardPageState>()!
```

I assume `DashboardPage.of(context)` is called somewhere, when it actually doesn't have a DashboardPage parent for that `context` instance. However, I cannot find it in the sample. Is it missing from it?

Comment: I have added the dart file where DashboardPage.of(context) is called

Comment: Just to verify, if you comment out the call to 'DashboardPage.of(context).showRaiseNewIssueForm(context)' and just have an empty function instead like '() {}', does the issue still occur?

Comment: yes, the error is still there. I replaced with {}.

Comment: That's unfortunate :/ Maybe `DashboardPage.of(context)` is still called somewhere else? What if you removed the `!` after `context.findAncestorStateOfType<_DashboardPageState>()!` and made it nullable? That might give a good indication. Or it's just another issue :(

Comment: I think the error is from misc.dart, can you please check it!